# Display tooltip on hover scrollable item

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having trouble displaying tooltips to a vertical navigation list.

Here's an example of my problem: *https://codepen.io/achillebourgault/pen/ZEVVbGe?editors=1100*

Basically, I have a parent div .leftnav-wrapper on which you can scroll up and down to unroll its content.
Each item is represented with a .listitem div and when you hover a tooltip is displayed. However, this tooltip is cut off, as it cannot exceed the width of the parent.

How can I solve this problem?

I first tried to have a  element display: inline-flex;
by displaying .leftnav-wrapper as the first element and .content as the second, but I still have the same problem.
I then tried putting  in relative position and .leftnav-wrapper in fixed position, but I still have the same problem.

```html
<main>
  <div class="leftnav-wrapper">
    <div class="leftnav">
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="listitem">
        <button>A</button>
        <div class="listitem-name">
          Example Item Name
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</main>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftnav-wrapper {
    width: 68px;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

.leftnav-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.leftnav-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.leftnav-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}

.leftnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}

.listitem {
  background: #cecece;
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.listitem-name {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 52px;
  transition; all 0.3s;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 999;
}

.listitem:hover .listitem-name {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition; all 0.3s;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 68px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
```

This is the code I was working on before creating a codepen to isolate the problem:

```js
import React from "react";

import styles from './LeftNavigation.module.css';

import {ServerListExample} from "../../assets/examples/ServerListExample";

export default function LeftNavigation() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.leftNavigation}>
            <div className={styles.listItem + " " + styles.privateMessages}>
                <div className={styles.listItemIcon + " " + styles.privateMessagesActive}>
                    <img src={"/images/discord-logo.png"} alt="Private Messages"/>
                    <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>Private Messages</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.listItemSep}></div>
            <div className={styles.serversList}>
                {
                    ServerListExample.map((server, index) => {
                        return server.type === 'server' ? (
                            <div className={styles.listItem} key={index}>
                                <div className={styles.listItemIcon}>
                                    <img src={server?.avatar} alt={server?.name}/>
                                    <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>{server?.name}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                            <div className={styles.listItemGroup} key={index}>
                                <div className={styles.listItemGroupTitle}>
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style={{color: 'rgb(88, 101, 242)'}}><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 7H12L10.553 5.106C10.214 4.428 9.521 4 8.764 4H3C2.447 4 2 4.447 2 5V19C2 20.104 2.895 21 4 21H20C21.104 21 22 20.104 22 19V9C22 7.896 21.104 7 20 7Z"></path></svg>
                                    <div className={styles.listItemGroupTitleName}>{server?.name}</div>
                                </div>
                                {server.childList.map((child, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className={styles.listItem} key={index}>
                                            <div className={styles.listItemIcon}>
                                                <img src={child?.avatar} alt={child?.name}/>
                                                <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>{child?.name}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
/* LeftNavigation.module.css */

.leftNavigation {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: var(--left-navigation-width);
    user-select: none;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: calc(100% - 16px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}

.listItem {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.listItemIcon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    align-items: stretch;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.privateMessages .listItemIcon {
    align-items: center;
}

.listItemIcon .listItemIconName {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: var(--black-100);
    color: #cecece;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.listItemIcon:hover .listItemIconName {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
}


.listItemIcon:hover,
.listItemIcon:hover > img {
    border-radius: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.listItemIcon > img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}

.privateMessages img {
    height: 26px !important;
    width: 26px !important;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.listItemSep {
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 66%;
    border-bottom: solid var(--grey-200) 2px;
}

.privateMessagesActive {
    background: #5764f0;
}

.listItemGroup {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    width: fit-content;
    place-self: center;
    background: var(--grey-300);
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.listItemGroup .listItem:last-child img {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.listItemGroupTitle {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 44px;
}

.listItemGroupTitle svg {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    fill: var(--grey-000);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.listItemGroupTitle .listItemGroupTitleName {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.listItemGroupTitle:hover .listItemGroupTitleName {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.serversList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

---

Comment: Is there a reason for the `overflow` rules on the `.leftnav-wrapper`?  It seems like you could just drop those rulex and have it render in full.

Comment: Yes, because the content of  `.leftnav-wrapper` will be dynamic, so you'll need to be able to scroll through it.

Comment: I doubt this could be resolved with mere CSS changes. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue) dives into `overflow` in more detail. Generally, once you introduce a scrollbar for Y, the X will start clipping.

Comment: Similar [use cases](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/#aa-the-solution) resort to JS to place the element next to the `:hover` item.  Since you're using react, You could leverage [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) to render a node outside of `overflow:auto`, you would have to position it yourself. A basic [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-portal-example-forked-mft84r?file=/src/index.js) could prove helpful.

Comment: The problem with this is that the tooltip follows the height of the scroll, whereas it should always be in the same position (even when scrolling) next to the corresponding item.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the CSS of the `main` by this :

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  background: black
}
```

and you replace the CSS of `.leftnav-wrapper` the by this :

```css
.leftnav-wrapper {
    width: 68px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It actually corrected my codepen problem. However, I tried to integrate the solution into my project and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

App.js

```js
// src/App.js
import React from 'react';
import TitleBar from "./components/TitleBar/TitleBar";

import LeftNavigation from "./components/LeftNavigation/LeftNavigation";
import LeftNavigationExtended from "./components/LeftNavigationExtended/LeftNavigationExtended";

import {useState} from "react";
import './assets/css/index.css';

function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name: 'JohnDoe74',
        avatar: 'https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/t_nbcnews-fp-1200-630,f_auto,q_auto:best/rockcms/2022-01/210602-doge-meme-nft-mb-1715-8afb7e.jpg',
        activity: 'online',
        microMuted: false,
        soundMuted: false,
    });

  return (
      <div className="parent">
        <TitleBar />

        <main>
            <div className="leftNavWrapper">
                <LeftNavigation />
            </div>
          <div className="content">
              <LeftNavigationExtended user={user} />
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.css

```css
.parent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.parent main {
    display: flex;
    /*height: calc(100vh - var(--title-bar-height));*/
}



.private-messages {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
    /*gap: 6px;*/
    /*padding: 8px;*/
    /*overflow-y: auto;*/
}

.content {
    /*border-top-left-radius: 8px;*/
    /*width: calc(100vw -var(--left-navigation-width));*/
    /*height: calc(100vh - var(--title-bar-height));*/
    /*background: var(--black-300);*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: white;
}


.leftNavWrapper {
    width: var(--left-navigation-width);
}

.leftNavWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
```

LeftNavigation.js

```js
import React from "react";

import styles from './LeftNavigation.module.css';

import {ServerListExample} from "../../assets/examples/ServerListExample";

export default function LeftNavigation() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.leftNavigation}>
            <div className={styles.listItem + " " + styles.privateMessages}>
                <div className={styles.listItemIcon + " " + styles.privateMessagesActive}>
                    <img src={"/images/discord-logo.png"} alt="Private Messages"/>
                    <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>Private Messages</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.listItemSep}></div>
            <div className={styles.serversList}>
                {
                    ServerListExample.map((server, index) => {
                        return server.type === 'server' ? (
                            <div className={styles.listItem} key={index}>
                                <div className={styles.listItemIcon}>
                                    <img src={server?.avatar} alt={server?.name}/>
                                    <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>{server?.name}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                            <div className={styles.listItemGroup} key={index}>
                                <div className={styles.listItemGroupTitle}>
                                    <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style={{color: 'rgb(88, 101, 242)'}}><path fill="currentColor" d="M20 7H12L10.553 5.106C10.214 4.428 9.521 4 8.764 4H3C2.447 4 2 4.447 2 5V19C2 20.104 2.895 21 4 21H20C21.104 21 22 20.104 22 19V9C22 7.896 21.104 7 20 7Z"></path></svg>
                                    <div className={styles.listItemGroupTitleName}>{server?.name}</div>
                                </div>
                                {server.childList.map((child, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div className={styles.listItem} key={index}>
                                            <div className={styles.listItemIcon}>
                                                <img src={child?.avatar} alt={child?.name}/>
                                                <div className={styles.listItemIconName}>{child?.name}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
/* LeftNavigation.module.css */

.leftNavigation {
    background: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: var(--left-navigation-width);
    user-select: none;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
    max-height: calc(100% - 16px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.leftNavigation::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}

.listItem {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.listItemIcon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    align-items: stretch;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.privateMessages .listItemIcon {
    align-items: center;
}

.listItemIcon .listItemIconName {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40px; /* Ajustez la position horizontale selon vos besoins */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: var(--black-100);
    color: #cecece;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.listItemIcon:hover .listItemIconName {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
}


.listItemIcon:hover,
.listItemIcon:hover > img {
    border-radius: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.listItemIcon > img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}

.privateMessages img {
    height: 26px !important;
    width: 26px !important;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.listItemSep {
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    width: 66%;
    border-bottom: solid var(--grey-200) 2px;
}

.privateMessagesActive {
    background: #5764f0;
}

.listItemGroup {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 12px;
    width: fit-content;
    place-self: center;
    background: var(--grey-300);
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.listItemGroup .listItem:last-child img {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.listItemGroupTitle {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 44px;
}

.listItemGroupTitle svg {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    fill: var(--grey-000);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.listItemGroupTitle .listItemGroupTitleName {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.listItemGroupTitle:hover .listItemGroupTitleName {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.serversList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a Codesandbox of your app?

Comment: Here the codesandbox link: https://rb.gy/vryex
I don't know why there's an error when launching codesandbox but you can just close it to see the page.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what is the problem. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Tooltips that appear when you hover one of the items in the list on the left are cut off, since they cannot exceed the width of the parent. So I isolated the problem in a codepen and @MHinfo found a suitable solution. However, I can't integrate the solution to this problem into my real project (discord clone), as the .listItemIconName are cut off when they appear as you can see on the codesandbox.

Comment: You have to remove `overflow-y: auto;` in `LeftNavigation.module.css`. If it is solving your problem, you can accept the previous answer!

Comment: This fixes the problem, but I need to use `overflow-y: auto;` or `overflow-y: scroll;` somewhere in leftNavigation or a parent, because this section must be scrollable if there are more elements or if the window size is smaller. And I don't want the whole app to scroll just leftNavigation or the parent.

Comment: In this case, use `overflow-y: visible;`

Comment: With `overflow-y: visible;` the object takes the height of the content, so you can't scroll inside the content :(

Comment: Ok. If you increase the length of the `.leftNavigation` element, and you change the `justify-content` or `place-selft` of `.listItem` and `.listItemGroup` for `flex-start`, it will fix the problem.

Comment: Does it work for you, @Achille?

Comment: No :/ it doesn't work or I've done it wrong, but I don't think so. Could you send me a private message please ?

Comment: There is no private message on Stackoverflow. However, you can send me an email (you can find my email on my website, which is on my profile infos)